# iPhone Core Location: Custom pin image disappears when map type changes

Tags: iphone, core-location

I have a segmented controller which sits on a MKMapView. When I change MKMapType, the image of my custom pins revert to the default red. The title and subtitle, along with coordinates remain intact. Can anyone shed some light on a possible solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had a similar problem a while ago.

[Why does a custom MKMapView annotation image disappear on touch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805897/iphone-annotation-image-disappears-on-touch)

Make sure you're using `MKAnnotationView` instead of `MKPinAnnotationView` everywhere in your `viewForAnnotation` method.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been struggling with this one for awhile now.