# how to change user location pin image in mkmapview type=satellite?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mkmapview

In `MKMapView` I am having two type of map that is `MKMapTypeStandard` and `MKMapTypeSatellite`.
 I want to replace user location pin to another(location.jpg) image.
The pin image is changing in `MKMapTypeStandard` (location.jpg) but in `MKMapTypeSatellite`(default image) pin image displayed as default map pin image.
 how can i solve this problem in project?

Here is my code.

```
MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:nil];

     MKPinAnnotationView *customPinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:nil];
    //customPinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mappin4"];
    if (!pinView)
    {
        if (annotation == mapView.userLocation)
        {
            customPinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mappin4"];

        }
        else
        {

        }
        customPinView.animatesDrop = NO;
        customPinView.canShowCallout = NO;
        customPinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
       return customPinView;

    } else
    {
       pinView.annotation = annotation;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this ;

```
 - (void) changeMapType: (id)sender
    {
        if (mapView.mapType == MKMapTypeStandard)
            mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;
        else
            mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
    }
```

So by default if you use google maps, it is in the form of **MKMapTypeStandard**.
you can change if you want by **mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite**;

you can also check following url ;

[Why does a custom MKMapView annotation image disappear on touch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805897/iphone-annotation-image-disappears-on-touch)

Make sure you're using **MKAnnotationView** instead of **MKPinAnnotationView** everywhere in your viewForAnnotation method.